# Is there a way to prevent forecasting negative values with ARIMA (or add constrains) in R?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, data-transformation

Currently I'm using the ARIMA provided in R, the training series is a seasonal time series, with some values close to zero in each period, and I find that when the training series have a descending trend, then in the result of the forecast, there will be some negative values.

But the time series should be positive on every timestamps, is there a way to add constraints in ARIMA so as to prevent forecasting negative values?

If adding constraints is not possible, is there a way to transform the predicted results so as to make them all positive and still capture the tendency?

Comment: Use the forecast package and set lambda=0 in either Arima() or auto.arima().

Comment: @RobHyndman Thanks! I have another question, setting lambda=0 is to apply the log transformation to the series, if there are some (very little) values are zero, will the model fitting fail? (In case that someone else use the function when they use zero for missing data)

Comment: In that case, try using log(x+1) instead.